# Issues with SVG Patterns in React

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js

I have been working on creating a wep app using svgs for card icons and have been running into issues regarding the  **pattern element inheriting its color property from other components** when I expect it to have its own unique color.

I believe this issue centers around the **xlinkHref property being non-unique** in the rendered svg components but would prefer to not have to change it for every instance of the component.

example:
The first set of Diamonds are as expected but the second one should have red stripes but is instead inheriting the green ones.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDP4e.png)

```js
// props = {color: (rgba), shape: 'diamond', pattern: ('empty', 'stripes', 'solid')}
function Shapes(props) {
  let pattern = (props.pattern == 'empty') ? '#00000000' : props.pattern;
  if(props.shape == 'diamond') { // diamond -----------------------------
    if(pattern !== '#00000000' ) {
      pattern = (pattern === 'stripes') ? 'url(#diamondStripes)' : props.color;
    }
    return (
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        height={props.height}
        version="1.1"
        viewBox="0 0 50 100"
      >
        <defs>
          <pattern
            id="diamondStripes"
            patternTransform="rotate(45) scale(.69545 1.34202)"
            xlinkHref="#Strips1_1_D"
          ></pattern>
          <pattern
            id="Strips1_1_D"
            width="2"
            height="1"
            patternTransform="scale(10)"
            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          >
            <path fill={props.color} stroke="none" d="M0 -0.5H1V1.5H0z"></path>
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <g fill="url(#Strips1_1)" fillOpacity="1">
          <path
            fill={pattern}
            fillOpacity="1"
            stroke={props.color}
            strokeDasharray="none"
            strokeMiterlimit="4"
            strokeWidth="3.308"
            d="M30.641 -26.22H81.919V25.058H30.641z"
            opacity="1"
            transform="scale(.62137 1.2704) rotate(45)"
          ></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    );
  } else { // empty
    return (
      <></>
    );
  }
};
export default Shapes;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Are there any workarounds or better practices?

Comment: Please post a minimum viable test case & avoid linking to outside resources to illustrate a problem (SO wants to avoid link rot).

Comment: id values must be unique within a document so if they're not that's going to be a problem.

Comment: Don't hardcode id values e.g. Strips1_1 in reusable components.

Answer (score 0):

Still not ideal but I have managed to steer away from hardcoded ids for the pattern  which does fix my issue though it is not pretty.

```js
// defs helper function ----------------------
let defs = (shape, color) => {
  if (shape == 'diamond') {
    return ( 
      <defs >
        <pattern 
          id = {`diamondStripes_${color}`}
          width = "2"
          height = "1"
          patternTransform = "rotate(45) scale(1.1)"
          patternUnits = "userSpaceOnUse" >
          <path 
            fill = {color}
            stroke = "none"
            d = "M0 -0.5H1V1.5H0z" 
          >< /path>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
    );
  }
}

function Shapes(props) {
  let pattern = (props.pattern == 'empty') ? '#00000000' : props.pattern;
  if (pattern !== '#00000000') {
    pattern = (pattern === 'stripes') ? `url(#${props.shape}Stripes_${props.color})` : props.color;
  }
  if (props.shape == 'diamond') { // diamond ---------------
    return ( 
      <svg 
        xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlnsXlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        height = {props.height}
        version = "1.1"
        viewBox = "0 0 50 100" >
        {defs(props.shape, props.color)}
        <g>
          <path 
            fill = {pattern}
            fillOpacity = "1"
            stroke = {props.color}
            strokeDasharray = "none"
            strokeMiterlimit = "4"
            strokeWidth = "3.308"
            d = "M30.641 -26.22H81.919V25.058H30.641z"
            opacity = "1"
            transform = "scale(.62137 1.2704) rotate(45)" >
          < /path> 
        </g>
      </svg>
    );
  } else { // empty ----------
    return ( 
      <></>
    );
  }
};

export default Shapes;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuLDd.png)